# React Material UI Select doesn't change value when selecting an item from the dropdown

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

This is part of my code.

I am fetching drugs and hard-coding categories based on their class. Then I am mapping the categories, checking if a drug matches the category. If yes, then the MenuItem appears under the specific ListSubHeader.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/drugs')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => setDrugs(json))

}, [drugs])

const [categories, setCategories] = React.useState([
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Miscellaneous analgesics"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Benzodiazepines"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Aminopenicillins"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Miscellaneous antimalarials"
  }
]);

const handleChange = (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.value);
  setPrescription({...prescription, drug: event.target.value});
}

<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="grouped-select">Pharmaceutical Drugs</InputLabel>
        <Select 
         id="grouped-select" 
         value={prescription.drug ? prescription.drug : ""} 
         onChange={handleChange}>
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          {categories.map(category => 
       (<span>
            <ListSubheader key={category.id}>{category.name}</ListSubheader>
            {drugs.map(drug => drug.class===category.name ? <MenuItem key={drug._id} value={drug.name}>{drug.name}</MenuItem> : null)}
       </span>)
    )}
        </Select>
        <FormHelperText>Select a Pharmaceutical Drug to prescribe.</FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> react_devtools_backend.js:2430 Material-UI: You have provided an
> out-of-range value `undefined` for the select component. Consider
> providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''. The
> available values are `1`, `2`, `3`

None of the values I select seem to work and show what I've selected as well. What am I doing wrong here?

I've adjusted the code a bit, if I add a dummy value to

```
<MenuItem value="">
        <em>None</em>
      </MenuItem>
```

Then I seem to be receiving a value from the console.log in handleChange, however, everything here returns me an undefined value. I've looked into React Developer Tools and every rendered MenuItem in the  does have a value, an id and everything.

```
{categories.map(category => 
       (<span>
            <ListSubheader key={category.id}>{category.name}</ListSubheader>
            {drugs.map(drug => drug.class===category.name ? <MenuItem key={drug._id} value={drug.value}>{drug.name}</MenuItem> : null)}
       </span>)
    )}
```

Comment: Your MenuItem value is empty

Comment: I've looked at react developer tools and it is not, the key is also being assigned properly everywhere.

Comment: your Select also doesn't have a value.

Comment: See my edited post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who still cares! The problem was with renderValue. I've made a renderValue function and passed it to select and return the value of the drug. Ensure to check material ui select docs if you guys get stuck. Nothing was wrong with my backend or front-end.

Solved!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution for it.

```
<Select
  value={plant}
  onChange={handleSelectChange}
  renderValue={(selected) => {
    if(selected)
      return plant.modelName
  }}
  >
  {plants.map((value) => (
    <MenuItem value={value}>{value.modelName}</MenuItem>
  ))}
</Select>
```

You have to add '**renderValue**' props to render the selected value.